# How can I use provider without context?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, provider

I have a widget where I use the provider but where I want to use the values is in normal widgets so maybe anyone can help.

This is where I use the provider :

```
  Widget _buildName(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Full Name',
              style: kLabelStyle3,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              height: 50.0,
              child: TextFormField(
                initialValue: UserData.fullname;
                validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Enter your Name' : null,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() => _currentfullname = val);
                },
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      width: 2.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  hintText: 'Enter your Name',
                  hintStyle: kHintTextStyle2,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );

  }
```

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final user = Provider.of<Userr>(context);
        return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
          stream: DatbaseService(uid:user.uid).userData,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              UserData userData =snapshot.data;
              return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  elevation: 0.0,
                ),
                body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
                  value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
                    child: Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            height: double.infinity,
                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 40.0,
                                vertical: 10,
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Center(
                                    child: Stack(
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                          width: 110,
                                          height: 110,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(

                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                                              image: DecorationImage(
                                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                  image: NetworkImage(
                                                    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3307758/pexels-photo-3307758.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=250",
                                                  ))),
                                        ),
                                        Positioned(
                                            bottom: 0,
                                            right: 0,
                                            child: Container(
                                              height: 35,
                                              width: 35,
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                border: Border.all(
                                                  width: 4,
                                                  color: Theme.of(context)
                                                      .scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                                                ),
                                                color: Colors.green,
                                              ),
                                              child: Icon(
                                                Icons.edit,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              ),
                                            )),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 10,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Mein Profil',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                                      fontSize: 20.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  showAlert2(),

                                    _buildEmailTF(),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 30.0,
                                  ),
                                  _buildName(),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 30.0,
                                  ),
                                  _builduserName(),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 30.0,
                                  ),
                                  _buildPasswordTF(),
                                  SizedBox(height: 30,),

                                  _buildPassword2TF(),
                                  _buildUpdateDataButton(),
                                  // _buildEmailform(),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              );

            }else{
return null;
            }


          }
        );


      }



  }
```

```
class DatbaseService{

  final String uid;
  DatbaseService({this.uid});
  //collection reference
  final CollectionReference myprofilsettings = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('meinprofilsettings');

  Future updateUserData(String user,String fullname,String password,String email)async{
    return await myprofilsettings.doc(uid).set({
      'username':user,
      'fullname':fullname,
      'passwort':password,
      'email':email,
    });

  }

  //profil list from snapshot
  List<myprofil> _myprofillistFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
      return myprofil(
        user: doc.data()['user']??'',
        fullname: doc.data()['fullname']??'',
        email: doc.data()['email']??'',
        passowrd: doc.data()['password']??'',


      );
    }).toList();
  }
  //userData from snapshot
  UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    return UserData(
      uid: uid,
      name: snapshot.data()['name'],
      fullname: snapshot.data()['fullname'],
      email: snapshot.data()['email'],
      password: snapshot.data()['password'],


    );
  }
  //get myprofilsettings stream
  Stream<List<myprofil>> get settings{
    return myprofilsettings.snapshots().map(_myprofillistFromSnapshot);
  }

  //get user doc stream
Stream<UserData> get userData{
    return myprofilsettings.doc(uid).snapshots().map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
}
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class Userr{

  final String uid;

  Userr({this.uid});



}
class UserData {
  final String uid;
  final String user;
  final String fullname;
  final String email;
  final String passowrd;

  UserData({this.uid,this.user,this.fullname,this.email,this.passowrd, name, password});
```

Ignore this:
Because flutter says __it looks like It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. ___
IM adding some  textdehpkfnwrfemrjfikerfoiwnfdoiwjefiojnweoidfjwiodjwiojdoijweiodjweiojdoiewjdijewoijdoejwdiojewiojdiowjedijweoidjiowediwjdoiwejdiowjdiojwoidjaldknjlncjnnc                xy,,y,y,,y,ykampkdnndendiowendiojweiopjdipqejkdpojkdposkqwpodkqopwkdopkqwopdskqopdkpoqwkdopqkwopdkqwpodkpoqkdpkqpodkpqkdpokdpo<skcpoaskdpoakdopkdpoekwopdkwepokdpowekdpokwepodkwepokdpowekdpowekpdkpekdpokeopdkpekdpowekdopewkpdkwpekdpwekdpowekdpowekdpowekdpkwepodkwepodkpoekdpoewkdpoekdp

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder<UserData>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<UserData, AsyncSnapshot<UserData>>#c612d):
A build function returned null.

The offending widget is: StreamBuilder<UserData>
Build functions must never return null.

To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return "Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return "Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<UserData> file:///Users/name/StudioProjects/project/lib/seitenleiste/meinacount.dart:356:16
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      debugWidgetBuilderValue.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:305:7)
#1      debugWidgetBuilderValue (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:326:4)
#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4592:7)
#3      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4759:11)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4281:5)
...
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: You can't use Provider without a BuildContext. Consider using https://riverpod.dev/ instead.
I hope this answer helps you, since the question is actually not clear enough.

Comment: hmm not really can you maybe show on my code how to doing that ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m assuming that your `_buildName()` is a method of your widget and that you call it from you build method somewhere.

This means that you can pass either the context or the user into this method:
`_buildName(BuildContext context) {}` or `_buildName(User user) {}`

Try providing more of the code next time, specifically the parts where you call the method.

Edit after post update:

You need to have the user object in the buildName method so you cannot simply do `UserData.fullname` because `UserData` is a class not an instance.

So to get your data in the buildName you need to change it to:

```dart
_buildName(UserData userData) {
  userData.fullname; // this now exists
}
```

And call is like: `_buildName(userData)`

Comment: it make sense and look at my code you're right I call it in the widget . But how can I use this what im showing. I mean the initialvalue in my method  _builName. when im using userData.fullname it shows undefined name

Comment: Please just include the whole widget, it’s not readable like this

Comment: hey sorry agin but I have a error and think it  not useful to create a new question I updating my maybe you can check. thanks !

Comment: The error explains what you did wrong, if you cannot figure it out open a new question